# setImageDrawable not having effect without existing content

Tags: android, user-interface, android-imageview

I have an ImageView define in XML like as follows:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

I'm attempting to set the image contents dynamically in code, based on some user action (they select an image from their library). I set the image using the following code:

```
    ImageView bgView = (ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.background);
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(wallpaper);
    bgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Calling this code has no immediate effect on the ImageView instance. However, if I put some sort of image into the XML definition, something like:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/test_image"/>
```

It works fine. Does anyone know what the cause of the issue might be? I've verified that the image setting code is running on the UI thread, and that the Drawable created is valid. The problem feels like it might be related to the layout not being performed correctly to reflect the added image?

Comment: bgView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.test_image) works?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that. The setImageDrawable call fails to do anything even if I put in a drawable from the /res/drawable folder, unless there's an existing content defined in XML.

Comment: I think more code might help in this instance. setImageDrawable works fine without needing to set a drawable in XML. I'm assuming there's something that may be affecting your results that's not a part of the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the issue was, after a bit more digging. In the case where an empty image is being set (that is, the default state when no custom background is found in the user settings), my code does .setImageDrawable(null) when the view is loaded. Removing this seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ImageView bgView = (ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(wallpaper);
// check d != null
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
bgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```